# Как проверить файл что он открыт?

Tags: c#, filestream

Подскажите как проверить файл открыт или закрыт?!

Пробовал способы из [Данной темы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987559/check-if-a-file-is-open) но не один не помог.

Пример использовал такой:

```
protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(string file)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
  {
     throw new ArgumentException("'path' cannot be null or empty.", "path");
  }
  try
  {
    using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) { }
  }
  catch (IOException)
  {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Дальше делал проверку

```
if(IsFileLocked(PathToFile))
{
  // открыт
}
else
{
  // закрыт
}
```

После запусти программу ( которую проверяю )
Но он постоянно мне пишет что файл открыт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Open_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_

Comment: @Дмитрий `IsFileLocked()` - почему без параметра? Мы об одном и том же коде говорим?

Comment: @4per вполне возможно